# NSURLCache cachedresponseforrequest no data

Tags: nsurlcache

why the responseCache is nil? i'd run this post and really get the responseObject from cache. How can i get the responseCache?

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

manager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy=NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad;

[manager POST:URL parameters:paramdic progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

    NSData * data=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:responseObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

    NSURLCache * cache=[NSURLCache sharedURLCache];

    NSCachedURLResponse * responseCache=[cache cachedResponseForRequest:task.originalRequest];

    NSCachedURLResponse * response=[[NSCachedURLResponse alloc]initWithResponse:task.response data:data userInfo:nil storagePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed];


    [cache storeCachedResponse:response forRequest:task.originalRequest];




} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three reasons it is `nil` at that point:

- POST requests are not cached by any iOS/OS X networking code because they are not guaranteed to be idempotent (i.e. they can have side effects, such as storing data on the server).  The only way a POST request will ever get stored in an `NSURLCache` is if you explicitly add it.
- POST requests are not cached because `NSURLCache` uses the URL as the lookup key.  Because the URL does not (cannot) include the POST body, any POST operations to the same URL would be returned for a different POST request, which is almost certainly not what you would want.  So if you do add it, you'll have to add some custom rewriting of the URL on its way into the cache and custom lookup code to make the URLs unique enough based on specific POST body fields or whatever.
- The cache is highly asynchronous, so cached data would not necessarily be available when the request's completion handler runs even if this were a GET request.

This is not necessarily a complete set of reasons.  :-)

The cache is intended to reduce network traffic.  You shouldn't generally consult it yourself.  The normal lookup path used by `NSURLSession` et al performs checks for certain protocol caching policies (e.g. response expiration) that would not be performed by merely asking the cache if it has a response for a particular key.

If you need a general mechanism for storing a single response for later use by your app (rather than keeping it in memory), you should do so in your own internal dictionary (or, if the response is large, by using a download task and moving the file into a temporary folder in your app's sandbox that you purge on every launch).

Comment: The responseCache code is added at second time running. In fact the data was cahced,i can find it in bundle.But second time code running,when i want to  get the data cached,i find its nil.

Comment: Are you sure that particular response was cached (as opposed to other requests)?  The response to a POST request is never, ever cached unless you added code to forcibly insert it (which you can do, but it is usually the wrong way to solve the problem).  What problem are you actually trying to solve by checking the cache?

Comment: I'm sorry for this reply after about a week because i token a holiday for my enteritis.Actually the problem is not about POST or GET. But thanks for the helping for understood of them. The problem is how i can get cached data  which i cached at the first  app running. The request onjects in two running times aren't  a same object but the url is uniqueness.why i can't get the cached data at the second time.

Comment: For a GET request, if the response isn't in the cache later (after a period of at least a few seconds), that means either A. your disk cache size isn't big enough (try setting the limit to ~100x the size of the largest item), B. the response was expired from the cache because of policies specified in the response header, C. the response was never stored because of policies specified in the response header, or D. your app exited before the response got into the cache.

Comment: Thanks! Policy isn't specified in the response header.It's done.UR my hero.